# iOS styling UITabBar only works on simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uiappearance

I'm developing an iPhone app and I am trying to style a UITabBar: I need to set the background image and selection image of a tab bar.

This is the code I am using:

```
- (void)customizeInterface
{
    UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tabbar"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selectiontab"]];
}
```

I am then calling

```
[self customizeInterface];
```

at the top of didFinishLaunchingwithOptions.

This **works perfectly on the simulator**, but on the device it doesn't work! On the device I get the usual black tabBar...anyone had similar issues?

Thanks.

EDIT:

SOLVED
The problem was in the png image: for some reason the iPhone didn't like the image's compression...I edited the image in fireworks, saved it again as a png and now it works both on the sim and on the device :-)

Comment: what's the version of iOS on your device?

Comment: file system on simulator isn't case-sensitive, unlike on device. Check your capitalisation.

Comment: @Andraw iOS version 6.1.3

Comment: @Kreiri Thanks, I've checked but I still have the problem: the png image doesn't get loaded on the device (i tried to nslog the size)...i can't understand why it doesn't get loaded...

Comment: try add extension .png to file name

Comment: try check on exists of the file NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Tabbar" ofType:@"png"];

Comment: try use imageWithContentsOfFile: instead of imageNamed: after check on existing file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The problem was in the png image: for some reason the iPhone didn't like the image's compression...I edited the image in fireworks, saved it again as a png and now it works both on the sim and on the device :-)